# Multi-master Bus Systems, Arbitration and Synchronization

Tags: microcontroller, clock, multi-master

I am slightly confused in the multi master system of Atmega328p. I have understood that first the clock is synchronized by taking the logic and gate of all. Then the data is synchronized and one master is considered. But I have a few questions. After the selection of one master it sends its data. Then How is the next master chosen. Will it consider the previous master in the next arbitration process or not? If it does take that in consideration that it means that this master will get its turn again and the other masters woun't get their turn. Kindly explain the process which happens???

Link: [Atmega328p](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: It's completely unclear what multimaster system you are talking about. UART, SPI, I2C or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*My understanding is you're asking about the multi-master mode of the 2-wire interface, per [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf) section 22*

The simple answer is that a master that loses arbitration ceases to be a master: it is required to go immediately into slave mode. (Section 22.4)

Once it's a slave, some other trigger will cause it to want to become a master again.  Typically these are external events such as reading a data value from its sensors, getting network or other message, or a timeout.

What stops a particular master from always winning the arbitration?  Only the logic of your code.  A common technique is randomised- backoff, often [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) with a cutoff (see for example TCP congestion control and the collision detection/retry in the original CSMA/CD Ethernet).  Another method is to [pass a token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_passing) from one node to the next to know which should be the next master (always with some timeout mechanism in case that is lost or the current master crashes.)

Of course, you might have ranked masters and always want the highest priority one to win.  (See for example [HSRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol) elections and [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol) labelling.)